# Python parsing file that has single and double quotes, as well as contractions

Tags: python, json, parsing, text-mining

I am trying to parse a file where some of the lines may contain a combination of single quotes, double quotes, and contractions.  Each observation includes a string as shown above.  When trying to parse the data, I am running into problems when trying to parse the reviews.  For example:

```
\'text\' : \'This is the first time I've tried really "fancy food" at a...\'
```

or

```
\'text\' : \'I' be happy to go back "next hollidy"\'
```

Comment: Why aren't you just using the `json` module?

Comment: @kindall  I am using the json module....Problem was the "json" I recieved is really not json as its format is  '{\'address_components\': [{\'long_name\': \'Fairhope\', \'short_name\':  ...      Which I have to do some reformating to get json.loads to work

Comment: The above string seems to be json though

Comment: @mad_  Not validating as JSON becuse it needs to be in double quotes and not single quotes so 'long_name' : 'Fairhope'   should be "long_name" : "Fairhope" or at least that is the only way I got pyton to read it as json.

Comment: Then the json tag is misleading as is the title, because you don't have JSON at all. But if it's not JSON the question can't be answered as no one except you, and maybe not even you, knows what you have there.

Comment: How about first escaping all `"` characters with `\"`, and then replacing all `\'` with `"`? Given your sample it should turn it into a valid JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preprocess your string with a simple double replace - first escape all the quotation marks, then replace all the escaped apostrophes with a quotation mark - which will simply invert the escapes, e.g.:

```
# we'll define it as an object to keep the validity
src = "{\\'text\\' : \\'This is the first time I've tried really \"fancy food\" at a...\\'}"
# The double escapes are just so we can type it properly in Python.
# It's still the same underneath:
# {\'text\' : \'This is the first time I've tried really "fancy food" at a...\'}

preprocessed = src.replace("\"", "\\\"").replace("\\'", "\"")
# Now it looks like:
# {"text" : "This is the first time I've tried really \"fancy food\" at a..."}
```

Which is now a valid JSON (and a Python dictionary, incidentally) so you can go ahead and parse it:

```
import json

parsed = json.loads(preprocessed)
# {'text': 'This is the first time I\'ve tried really "fancy food" at a...'}
```

Or:

```
import ast

parsed = ast.literal_eval(preprocessed)
# {'text': 'This is the first time I\'ve tried really "fancy food" at a...'}
```

**UPDATE**:

Based on the posted line, you actually have a (valid) representation of a 7-element tuple containing a string representation of a dictionary as its third element, you don't need to preprocess the string at all. What you need is to first evaluate the tuple, then post-process the inner `dict` with another level of evaluation, i.e.:

```
import ast

# lets first read the data from a 'input.txt' file so we don't have to manually escape it
with open("input.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.read()

data = ast.literal_eval(data)  # first evaluate the main structure
data = data[:2] + (ast.literal_eval(data[2]), ) + data[3:]  # .. and then the inner dict

# this gives you `data` containing your 'serialized' tuple, i.e.:
print(data[4])  # 31.328237,-85.811893
# and you can access the children of the inner dict as well, i.e.:
print(data[2]["types"])  # ['restaurant', 'food', 'point_of_interest', 'establishment']
print(data[2]["opening_hours"]["weekday_text"][3])  # Thursday: 7:00 AM – 9:00 PM
# etc.
```

That being said, I'd suggest tracking down whoever is generating data like this and convince them to use some proper form of serialization, even the most basic JSON would be better than this.

Comment: thanks for the insight, but not quite working for me.  Once I tried that it gave me problems parsing that was not there before.  For instantce on this part: \'adr_address\': \'<span class=\"street-address\">913 Rucker Blvd #34</span>, <span class=\"locality\">Enter

Comment: @nbas - Can you post the actual string you're trying to parse and what do you expect out of it? The extracted parts should be _fixable_ by the above routine but there might be some parts that do not follow the pattern.

Comment: I have updated my orginal question wat one of lines that is giving me difficultites. It is on the top of the page.